# C++ - array type 'unsigned __int64 [amount*]' is not assignable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm writing implementation of algorithm in Visual 2015 and in this part of code

```
int amount;
//some code that change value of variable amount
uint64_t table[amount*9];
```

a got an error

```
array type 'unsigned __int64 [amount*]' is not assignable
```

I read that i should initialize an array so i did

```
uint64_t table[amount*9] = {0};
```

But it didn't help.
Any suggestions ??

Comment: amount needs to be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't support variable sized arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead:

```
    int amount;
    //some code that change value of variable amount
    std::vector<uint64_t> table(amount*9);
```

Comment: @piter_os Accepting the answer would be appreciated.